# Google flights mobile app feedback/research

Tags: usability, user-research, user-centered-design, research, case-studies

I created a mock-up mobile app for Google flights for a UX design project. Does anyone have any pain points when it comes to mobile flight search whether on:

- Google
- Existing mobile apps like Expedia, Skyscanner, Hopper, FlightAware, etc
- Existing airline apps like Delta, United, Alaska, etc

Are there features when it comes to your flight search that you wish you could have that you don’t see featured anywhere?

Anything is great feedback thank you.
I have created a page for my case study so far if you feel inclined to have a visual understanding of the mobile application.
https://loumarar.com/2/

Comment: More a feature than a UX issue, but what no usual flight booking UI has and I badly want is "you tell _me_ when is cheapest". Though it seems it's _very_ difficult because of how prices are set...

Comment: @PabloH Albeit in a limited timeframe, google flights has a few charts to show prices over time. Top right corner there are the Date Grid, to show the total cost of a certain leave/return date, and the price graph, to show how much x days leaving on x date would cost. They are both incredibly helpful. They even have a popup when relevent showing "you can pay less if you leave on X date" that shows up as soon as you do a search

Comment: Other search engines implemented "anywhere" destinations and "full month" date selection to give you the change of getting the lowest price in a certain period or for a certain destination

Answer (score 12):

That's going to be tough.

I've skimmed your existing text, and you make it sound like Google Flights is currently *not* user-centered. That's blankly incorrect. The first thing you've got to realize is that gFlights is *very, very* good. They built this service with a specific UX approach, over ten years, with millions of dollars of research, and the only reason that gFlights is the first in your list of examples today is the fact that Google built it so well (I'm not a Google fanboy, but credit where credit is due).

So, **if you're blindly attacking gFlights and "improve" the design without understanding the thousands of considerations they made for different users, you are going to look unprofessional**.

I think you have a chance if you look at very specific niches. Maybe people with only cabin luggage that don't want to pay a fee for non-existing big luggage are underserved? Maybe if you set your language to Greenlandic the long words break the UI?

Check out something like that, and you may have a chance to design a genuine improvement :)

Comment: This is a great answer. You sir, are a true professional of the craft. An application designed by the likes of google who has a team of UX experts not to mention people from their Material team should know good UX.

Comment: @jax Yes, they *should* know good UX.  But substantial evidence documents they often do not implement good UX.

Comment: You're right. Maybe I worded my response a bit too strongly. In fact, I am sure that the gFlights team missed some UX stuff, even though and maybe because of the large budgets, team and time span. Still think it's wise to assume that the existing UX is already quite good, which is not an assumption I would grant for all the software out there ;)

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Who is 'they'. If you are talking about other lesser companies, then yes - many don't necessarily even have a dedicated UI/UX designer. Instead, they might rely on a few decent full stack devs. However, if you are referring to big companies like Google that can hire teams of UI/UX professionals, then they do in fact have stellar UI/UX. I think you really underestimate have much cash Google can spend on UI/UX.

Comment: @jax Companies that do not hire (or subcontract) dedicated UI/UX professionals do so at their own peril.  Many large companies can (and should) invest heavily in dedicated UI/UX professionals, but alas, many do not.  And even for the companies that do, the abilities of the people they hire are sometimes less than stellar.  I have been **consistently unimpressed with the quality of UI/UX at Google**, and that's using the most generous terms possible.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I don't know why you keep making the assertion that big companies like Google have bad UX. There is no such evidence to support that assertion. Your opinion is extremely subjective. I have developed numerous mobile apps, with a focus on good UX. I know something about good UX.  And I am consistently very impressed with their UX, as well as Microsoft. Apple is good, but a little bland for me.

Comment: @jax Your claim that *"there is no such evidence to support that assertion"* is patently false.  I don't know why you can't see what is apparent to others.  But if the breadth of your experience and education in the field is just writing some mobile apps and perhaps taking 1 or 2 classes, that would certainly explain it.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket My claim is not false. It is fact. You have not provided any evidence.  Your previous claims and your current claim of 'Apparent to others' is not evidence. I have created over 10 mobile apps. And I also have a degree in software engineering. So I am as qualified as any.

Comment: @jax You mistakenly think you are qualified when you are not. You don't have a degree in the UX field. You have no experience running usability tests. You have no experience running a human factors lab. You have no experience or accomplishments in the UX industry. You have literally only learned how to code & have only written apps for 1 or 2 mobile platform(s). I could present you with vast evidence, but you don't have the education, experience, or knowledge to know what to do that all that evidence. I'm sorry, but you don't even understand the basics of what makes one qualified.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I never said I knew enough to be a UX designer. What I said was I knew enough to know that Google's UX is NOT bad.  Let me ask you this: What do you consider to be good UX? What do you prefer over Google?

Comment: @jax Please familiarize yourself with Stack Exchange.  I was willing to respond to you a few times in this comment thread while these comments remained relatively on-topic, but I'm not willing to continue responding to you here as it's not appropriate and your questions are now clearly completely off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

A few things I would find useful or more user-friendly:

1. You added a "round-trip" dropdown (and most travel apps do this). But why ? It seems easier to me to select a departure date, and If I want a return, add a return date. Adding a return date makes it a round-trip search.
2. Same for "economy": might not be a criteria for a lot of people, and no one will turn down a business-class ticket if it's cheaper than the economy one. If I want a minimum level of comfort, then I would expect to be able to add a filter for it. But that filter doesn't have to be one of the first fields to fill.
3. A lot of travel apps don't make it easy to edit a search from the results page.
4. I see you've dropped the pages to search at an unknown date, or see the price graph for a whole month. These are super useful.
5. A lot of apps let you add several departure cities, But I think no app lets you choose several arrival cities without specifying a departure city. This would be quite useful to me. I understand it's quite niche, but say you're travelling and you have many options where to go now (think interrail or digital nomads), you just need to be at a specific place in a month's time. Then you might want to pick where to go now based on what will be easy/cheap in a month. (I think only Kiwi does that part of the search well if you want to try it, but then their booking experience is much less good)
6. Include other transport methods (train, bus, car-sharing, ferries). Flying is only one way to get from A to B.
7. And maybe make it possible to combine methods (e.g. fly to London then train to somewhere else in England, with enough time in between, and insurance if you miss the train because of a late flight)
8. Also I can't be the only one who's annoyed by low-cost companies advertising great prices, only to have to add expensive luggage. It would make it easier if you could compare what's comparable directly in the search. Say, in your filters, you say "either without luggage or with 1 piece of hand luggage per person" and in the results you get, for each flight, both the price without hand luggage and the price with 1 piece. Though I suppose the data is not easily available for this, otherwise google would have probably done it already.